# Unable to reset all check box to unchecked in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to reset all my appended checkbox to uncheck form. But When I wrote new javascript code to make all checkbox to uncheck.My form does not allow me to even add these checkboxes

My html code

```
    <h1>Add or reset all </h1>
    <hr>
    <br>
    <button type="button" id="btn" onclick="addItems">Add Item</button>

    <input type="text" id="texto">
     <ul id="ul"> </ul>
```

My javascript code :

```
    function addItem(){

    var ul = document.getElementById('ul'); //ul
    var li = document.createElement('li');//li

    var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
        checkbox.type = "checkbox";
        checkbox.value = 1;
        checkbox.name = "todo[]";

    li.appendChild(checkbox);

    var text = document.getElementById('texto');
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text.value));
    ul.appendChild(li); 
    }

    var button = document.getElementById('btn');
    button.onclick = addItem;
```

When I add this function to make the all appended checked boxes to uncheck it did not even allow me to add the checkboxes into my form

```
 <input type="button" onclick="uncheckAll2()" class="btn btn-link" value="Uncheck All">
```

And Javascript function

```
 function uncheckAll2() 
  {
  var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.check2');
  for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  inputs[i].checked = false;
  }
```

Can you fix it out? Thanks in Adv.

Comment: I see no class `check2` being added to the checkboxes.

Comment: I know about that. But even when I add this function  uncheckAll2 it did not allow my to add /append checkboxes in the list

Comment: @NinjaNinja can you show the code how you are adding the class

Comment: No clue what that means. It is hard to find an element with a class when you did not add the class. `document.querySelectorAll('.check2')` is not going to find anything when you did add the class `check2` to the input in your code above. We expect to see something like `checkbox.className = 'check2'` or `checkbox.classList.add('check2')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The checkboxes does not have any class. You can add class or use `document.querySelectorAll('input[name="todo[]"]')` to select all input with this name and then iterate the collection and set `checked` to `false`

```js
function uncheckAll2() {
  var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="todo[]"]');
  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].checked = false;
  }
}
function addItem() {
  var ul = document.getElementById('ul'); //ul
  var li = document.createElement('li'); //li
  var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
  checkbox.type = "checkbox";
  checkbox.value = 1;
  checkbox.name = "todo[]";

  li.appendChild(checkbox);

  var text = document.getElementById('texto');
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text.value));
  ul.appendChild(li);
}

var button = document.getElementById('btn');
button.onclick = addItem;
```

```html
<h1>Add or reset all </h1>
<hr>
<br>
<button type="button" id="btn" onclick="addItems">Add Item</button>

<input type="text" id="texto">
<ul id="ul"> </ul>
<input type="button" onclick="uncheckAll2()" class="btn btn-link" value="Uncheck All">
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with `document.querySelectorAll('.check2');` No check box has .check2 class. Try to add class .check2 while adding new checkbox.

```
<h1>Add or reset all </h1>
<input type="button" onclick="uncheckAll2()" class="btn btn-link" value="Uncheck All">
<hr>
<br>
<button type="button" id="btn" onclick="addItems">Add Item</button>

<input type="text" id="texto">
<ul id="ul"> </ul>
<script>
    function addItem() {

        var ul = document.getElementById('ul'); //ul
        var li = document.createElement('li');//li

        var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
        checkbox.type = "checkbox";
        checkbox.value = 1;
        checkbox.name = "todo[]";
        checkbox.className = "check2";
        li.appendChild(checkbox);

        var text = document.getElementById('texto');
        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text.value));
        ul.appendChild(li);
    }

    var button = document.getElementById('btn');
    button.onclick = addItem;

    function uncheckAll2() {
        var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.check2');
        for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
            inputs[i].checked = false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: No need to add a class for no reason if he can just select for the name attribute with the value todo[], which is the same for all of the specified checkboxes.

Comment: They are multiple ways to do. I had identified the problem in class name so I added class. Even ("input[]type=checkbox") can also be used. It depends on how you think.

Comment: Your solution works as well, just wanted to state it for the sake of conversation :)

Comment: Happy coding. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function addItem(){
//console.log('adding');

var ul = document.getElementById('ul'); //ul
var li = document.createElement('li');//li

var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
    checkbox.type = "checkbox";
    checkbox.value = 1;
    checkbox.name = "todo[]";

li.appendChild(checkbox);

var text = document.getElementById('texto');
li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text.value));
ul.appendChild(li); 
}

var add_button = document.getElementById('add-btn');
add_button.onclick = addItem;


 function uncheckAll2() 
  {
   $(':checkbox').each(function() {
 this.checked = false;
 });

}

  var rem_button = document.getElementById('remove-btn');
rem_button.onclick = uncheckAll2;
```

HTML

```
 <h1>Add or reset all </h1>
 <hr>
 <br>
<button type="button" id="add-btn" onclick="addItems">Add Item</button>

<input type="text" id="texto">
 <ul id="ul"> </ul>
```